# publish new defined message type in ros indigo

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish new type message like std:map which store obstacle information.How can i do that?
Could you give me some suggestions. Thanks so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207669/publish-new-defined-message-type-in-ros-indigo/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to create a .msg file in a msg/ directory. You can create the message using the [ROS Message Description Language](http://wiki.ros.org/action/show/msg?action=show&redirect=ROS%2FMessage_Description_Language).

Then you will need to add some info about the message to your package.xml and CMakeLists.txt see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages).

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2015-04-24**:
thanks so much